# Uncheck all checked checkboxes when onBackPressed in android

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a listview with checkboxes. I arrange my listview in an EventHandler class. I want to uncheck all the checkboxes when back button is pressed. I call the onBackPressed method in another activity. So should I write another function for that returns a view. Please help. I searched a lot but I could not find exact solution.

Inside the class: I get an arraylist of Viewholders to uncheck the checkboxes.

```
private ArrayList<ViewHolder> mViewHolders = new ArrayList<>();
```

**ViewHolder:**

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView topView;
    TextView bottomView;
    TextView dateView;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

**getView:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    int num_items = 0;
    String temp = mFileMang.getCurrentDir();
    File file = new File(temp + "/" + mDataSource.get(position));
    String[] list = file.list();

    if(list != null)
        num_items = list.length;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, parent, false);

        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mViewHolder.topView =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_view);
        mViewHolder.bottomView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_view);
        mViewHolder.dateView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_view);
        mViewHolder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
        mViewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_checkBox);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }  // I also make some text setting inside this.
```

Comment: Create a callback in activity, in onBackPressed(), fire callback method, in your adapter, implement the callback and in callback method body, uncheck checkboxes.

Comment: But also take into account cases when you want to disable one check box, or only visible,or just all of them.

Comment: I want to clear all of them

Comment: Why for you need to rely on viewholders - as for me better would be to have the "mIsChecked" boolean inside your dataset depending on which you will set checked either unchecked state of the checkbox. When clicking back button just go over the dataset and make all mIsChecked == false and call notifyDataSetChanhed()

Comment: @EagleEye I do not know how to do all that can you help a little?

Comment: @gunescelil i suggest you to store checkbox value in pref and change the value of checkbox onbackpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment the workflow should be like this : 

 Your Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;
private List<YourCustomClass> mYourCustomItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // don't forget to init everything you need
    mYourCustomItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mYourCustomItems);
    mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode){
        case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            //all your needed stuff
            for (YourCustomClass item : mYourCustomItems){
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<YourCustomClass> mYourCustomClasses;

    public CustomAdapter(List<YourCustomClass> yourCustomClasses) {
        mYourCustomClasses = yourCustomClasses;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mYourCustomClasses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mYourCustomClasses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //all view holder related stuff and other initialization
        CheckBox checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(mYourCustomClasses.get(position).isChecked());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Yurii more than I need.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to store checkbox values in pref and change the value of checkbox onbackpress

To Store Boolean Array in Pref

```
public boolean storebaray(Boolean[] array, String arrayNam, Context mContext) {   

    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("prefname", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayNam +"size", array.length);  

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putBoolean(arrayNam + "_" + i, array[i]); 

    return editor.commit();  
}
```

the you can load that array

```
public Boolean[] loadAry(String arrayNam, Context mContext) {  

    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("prefname", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayNam + "size", 0);  
    Boolean array[] = new Boolean[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getBoolean(arrayNam + "_" + i, false);  

    return array;  
}
```

then onBackPressed check the values